# Can I autofill a pattern that changes periodically?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to create an autofill similar to below, essentially requiring excel to realise that every 3 cells down the row number being referenced increases by 10. I have tried but it does not seem to recognise the pattern. Is there any way around this?

```
='Book1'!$A1:$D17
='Book1'!$A1:$D17
='Book1'!$A1:$D17
='Book1'!$A11:$D17
='Book1'!$A11:$D17
='Book1'!$A11:$D17
='Book1'!$A21:$D17
='Book1'!$A21:$D17
='Book1'!$A21:$D17
```

Comment: No, excel won't be smart enough to understand that...

Answer (score 3):

The pattern or sequence that we want to generate is of the form

```
1,1,1,11,11,11,21,21,21,31...
```

An excel function will generate this is

```
=10*(FLOOR(ROW()-1,3)/3)+1
```

#### Explanation

The essence of this function is the `FLOOR(ROW,3)` part, which rounds down the row number of each cell to the nearest 3, so we get a pattern of

```
0,0,0,3,3,3,9,9,9,11,...
```

after an offset of `1` since we start counting rows 1 not 0. So now we have built upto `FLOOR(ROW()-1,3)`

We then divide by 3, and multiply it by 10 to get a sequence to get

```
0,0,0,10,10,10,20,20,20,30...
```

and add 1 to get it into the form that we need.

#### ... back to the task at hand

We can then use the `INDEX` function to reference a series of areas that you indicated

```
=INDEX(A:D,10*(FLOOR(ROW()-1,3)/3)+1,1):INDEX(A:D,17,4)
```

The first index references a cell at `A1,A1,A1,A11 ...` The second references a fixed cell at D17 -- Row 17, Column D (4)

Comment: Thank you peanut_butter, much appreciated. Would you be kind enought to advise how the end formula would look if i were aiming for below rather (i.e. row and column change).Tks                   ='Book1'!$A1:$D1
='Book1'!$A1:$D1
='Book1'!$A1:$D1
='Book1'!$A11:$D11
='Book1'!$A11:$D11
='Book1'!$A11:$D11
='Book1'!$A21:$D21
='Book1'!$A21:$D21
='Book1'!$A21:$D21

Comment: All you would have to do is change the final formula to `=INDEX(A:D,10*(FLOOR(ROW()-1,3)/3)+1,1):INDEX(A:D,10*(FLOOR(ROW()-1,3)/3)+1,4)`, i.e. change the row in the start and the final index to be of the same pattern.